# How to inspect elements on dynamically created DOM by using IE developers tools

Tags: css, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

I have a bug that I experience only in IE. I would like to inspect DOM by using IE developers toolbar, but unfortunately cannot seem to do it as complete DOM is generated dynamically. Does anybody have an idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: once that div is generated dynamically -- then inspect it.. :P

Comment: OK, Vivek, at the first glance I thought that you are joking me. But actually you are absolutely right, my problem was that I had IE developer tools switched on for the whole time. If I let the page load and than turn on the developers toolbar after everything is generated than all is nice and easy. Thank you Vivek, I would gladly accept you comment as an answer but it doesn't seem to be doable

Comment: I to always just had developer tools open all the time, and just assumed IE tools were not capable of handling dynamically added elements to the dom.

Comment: Yes :) But, actually, IE dev tools has a refresh button (should see it just beside the save icon), that serves just that purpose. When DOM elements are added on the fly, just refresh, and you'll be able to inspect them, best

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is a reload button in the toolbar to the right of the floppy disc icon. Hitting this also works.

Comment: This has the added benefit of preserving the state of the Browser/Document mode in case you were trying to emulate an older version of IE. If you open developer tools after the div has been dynamically generated and then set Browser/Document mode, the page will refresh.

Comment: ......... you are a superhero, for real. I have been doing IE dev for 10 years and it never occurred to me that that refresh button was a DOM refresh, always thought it would refresh the page.

Comment: Is there still a way to reload the DOM in IE11?

Comment: Using the official Windows 8.1 + Internet Explorer 11 VM images provided by Microsoft, I'm not seeing the button in the toolbar. I could've sworn it existed before... https://i.imgur.com/MCLI4th.png

Answer (score 12):

Once that div is generated dynamically, then inspect it. Answered it as it seemed to work for you... :)

Comment: Actually the real point is that developer tools must be closed when the content is generated, otherwise they won't appear in the inspector.

Comment: This really should not be the accepted answer. The correct answer is @jdln's below, or Korri's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

once page is completely loaded then click F12, after that reload page again and then on developer toolbar click REFRESH button which is available to exactly next to save button in developer tool bar. After that click the arrow for inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, make sure Inspector pane is active then hit F5 key.