# Auto-refresh HTML tab in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

I made a nice website that does a lot of DOM manipulation. Works very nicely in chrome and firefox. Though the client has requested now that it also works in Internet Explorer. The latest version is good enough to start with (that would be 10.0.9200.16721 in my case).

So the adventure starts, i press F12 and see a set of pretty familiar developer tools (coming from chrome and firebug). As i'm tracking the JS code i notice that the HTML tab (with the DOM) doesn't actually update.

According to the manual here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx  it's "a good idea to refresh the HTML tab to get the current DOM, especially when you use dynamic elements." (d0h ??) problem is .. i can't find a button to enable automatic update of the HTML tab. So i would have to click the refresh button everytime i step into a new line of JS (never mind of real-time DOM view).

But that's not all ... every time i click the refresh button the whole DOM tree view collapses. And i have to click a bunch of pluses to view the node i'm interested in.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Because what would take days will take weeks this way...

Comment: And that's why nobody likes IE.

Comment: IE11 has realtime updating of the DOM tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [How to inspect elements on dynamically created DOM by using IE developers tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359905/how-to-inspect-elements-on-dynamically-created-dom-by-using-ie-developers-tools)

From doing a little digging aroung, it seems like this is an issue other people have reported too. [This thread](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/216#issuecomment-15504011) might be of some interest to you.

The most relevant part of it:

> The problem is when you modify the dom (with or without jquery) from a callback which is called by a timeout, which is in a callback bound to an event, IE freaks out and doesn't update the dom tree in the development tool. Subsequent modifications to the changed tag in the dev tool won't have any effect.
>
> According to my tests, it's the combination of that sequence of calls that make this happen. If the dom is modified from a settimeout callback but without being inside of an event callback, it works. If instead of settimeout you directly call a function that modifies the dom, it works.

[Here](http://dropshado.ws/post/46430148565/refresh-button-in-ie-developer-tools)'s a working example of what you're saying to compound the issue.

Basically, this is an issue with IE. There is no fix available at the moment. The accepted answer on the other thread seems like a very poor workaround.

Comment: Ok that certainly is some nice info to know that it is buggy too. However i was asking how to automatically update the HTML tab without clicking the refresh button. Are you saying that it normally (without timeout) it would refresh automatically? If so .. i seriously question what the function of the refresh button is, if it was already automatically refreshing in the first place (considering a situation without timeout bug) ...

Comment: @Flip I know what you're asking. And what my answer says is that it can't be done. It would be a great feature for Microsoft to add, but currently you need to reload.